# Freya 0.3.2_20151209 does not boot from CD - it goes to Grub

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

I have tried to download 2 times freeway 0.3.2 ISO, burned into CD and boot from it but it shows me always GNU GRUB page,

Is there any way to fix it ? because all ways that I found in internet is to solve after finished installation.

thank you for any help,

ASUS Ultrabook Intel Core i5

Comment: Can you try burning it to a USB using Rufus. Maybe the CD is corrupt (I do not recommend CDs because they are slow and get corrupt)

Comment: Do you have UEFI.On my UEFI laptop it also shows the grub menu asking what to do and I click try

Answer (score 1):

The ISO will boot to Grub initially. That's the intended behavior.

From there, you can choose whether to try Elementary OS or install it. If you select "Try Elementary OS", are you able to boot? If not, do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

When powering on your machine, go to the BIOS and look for the "Boot" tab (or something with a similar name). Set the top priority to "USB" (also sometimes called USB-HDD or simply HDD).